# What is $|x-y|$ here?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I feel confused about this paragraph. What does $|x-y|$ mean here? Taking every element of a vector positive? Or length of a vector? I feel so confused.
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the length of the vector $x-y$. You can see this in the line that follows:
$$
x-y=\sqrt{(x-y)\cdot(x-y)}=\sqrt{x\cdot x+y\cdot y-2x\cdot y}=\sqrt{|x|^2+|y|^2-2x\cdot y}.
$$

Comment: I updated the question. Can you help me see why we can get derivative with respect to length?

Comment: It is the equation (2.25)

Comment: Can you help me with how to do the "direct calculation" to get (2.25)?